# Cassandra and Go API

Tags: json, go, cassandra

I am trying to integrate RESTful Golang API with Cassandra and getting the following error:

> 2018/06/01 13:28:02 http: panic serving [::1]:52037: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

and also my request is

```
{
    "col1": "sampleapp",
    "col2": "sampleappprev",
    "col3": "hadsh",
    "col4": "hasha"
}
```

but its getting printed as numbers

> [123 10 9 34 98 108 111 99 107 95 104 97 115 104 34 58 32 34 115 97 109 112 108 101 97 112 112 34 44 10 9 34 112 114 101 118 95 98 108 111 99 107 95 104 97 115 104 34 58 32 34 115 97 109 112 108 101 97 112 112 112 114 101 118 34 44 10 9 34 109 105 110 101 114 95 105 100 34 58 32 34 104 97 100 115 104 34 44 10 9 34 98 108 111 99 107 95 115 105 103 110 97 116 117 114 101 34 58 32 34 104 97 115 104 97 34 10 125]

Comment: Below your panic you should have a stack trace that will point to the line number where the nil pointer lives.  Paste that and the related line to make it easier to help you.

Comment: add the code also which generated these error